# Generate specific number of entities in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

The problem is the following: We want to generate a specific number of simevent entities?
What is the best way to achive this? We have an event based signal that has a specific value e.g. 5.
Now we want to generat 5 entities. The Event based generator only generates 1 entity. We tried to do it with a countdown timer but its not really working so far.

Comment: good question! I faced it times ago and can't find solution. What I did - create maximum number of inputs and use only part of them based on this value (5 in your example).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the new SimEvents library (I have 2017a, but it should work since 2016a). The trick is to set the time span dt to inf after N entities. Concrete: Open the Entity Generator parameters, choose "MATLAB action" for "Time source" and enter the following "Intergeneration time action":

```
T = 1;   % fixed intergeneration time
N = 5;   % number of entities generated
persistent nr;
if isempty(nr)
  nr = 1;
end

if nr <= N
  dt = T;
else
  dt = inf;
end
nr = nr + 1;
```

One can use it like that or better add a mask to define T and N.